# PHP not including connection info, what's wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, include

I'm trying to roll a CMS website and I'm on 1and1 Internet's hosting. I'm trying to connect to my MySQL database and I get the following error:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

After some frustration, I decided to check my include and it turns out that the following code is not including my connection variables file.

**admin.php**

```
<?php

include("connection.php");

$link = mysql_connect($connection_server, $connection_user, $connection_password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);

?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php

/* --------------------------------------
/
/   Bitachon.org Connection Variables
/   
/   Created by: Moshe [Last Name]
/
/
/   Date: October 12, 2010
/
/
/   This file contains the connection 
/   variable to connect to the MySQL
/   database that powers [site]
/
/  --------------------------------------*/

//Variable to confirm that the file has been included
$connnections_included = true;


/* --- Connection Variables ---*/

$connnection_server = "[server]";

$connection_database = "[db]";

$connection_user =  "[username]";

$connection_password = "[password]";

?>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with the code. Contact your hosting provider for support, it's most likely their fault.

Comment: @NullUserException - Could it be a security thing, like something a chmod can fix?

Comment: Does `$connection_server` happen to be localhost? Then try 127.0.0.1. Or vice versa

Comment: What happens if you write the connection parameters directly in the `mysql_connect` call (i.e. without using variables, just put the strings there)

Comment: does it work if you dont include connect.php, and simply put the raw values in mysql_connect, rather than variables?

Comment: @Ross, @Nico - It works when embedded in the admin file. It's an include problem.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before `mysql_connect()`. Do you get notices about undefined variables?

Comment: @Lekensteyn - Yes, I do.

Comment: @Moshe - might be related http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/

Comment: @Ross - I doubt it, because when I embed the variables in admin.php, it works.

Comment: In the interest of transparency this is now being discussed live at [The Roach Motel](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224/the-roach-motel)

Comment: In the interest of transparency, this was solved at the Roach Motel. (Follow @Josh's link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in your connection.php file, where there is a typo:

```
$connnection_server = "[server]";
  // ^-- third n
```

Fixing that (along with the `include()` issue mentioned in [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927051/php-not-including-connection-info-whats-wrong/3927557#3927557)) should resolve your problem.

Comment: Lol, yep. Thanks for help at the Roach Motel. (add the bit about the `http://` please.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have the path set correctly

```
include("/path/to/connection.php");
```

Check permissions on connection.php, test to see if it's readable

```
$filename = 'connection.php';
if(is_readable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is readable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not readable';
}
```

Is the MySQL Database on the same server? AKA Localhost or another server?

Hard code the path

```
$pwd = `pwd`;
echo "PWD: ".$pwd."<br />"; // use just for testing
include($pwd."/connection.php");
```

EDIT:
Can you compare connection.php and admin.php

```
$filename = 'admin.php';

echo "Permissions: ".substr(sprintf("%o",fileperms($filename)),-4)."<br />";
echo "File Owner: ".fileowner($filename)."<br />";
echo "File Group: ".filegroup($filename)."<br />";

if(is_executable($filename)) {
    echo ("$filename is executable<br />");
} else {
    echo ("$filename is not executable<br />");
}

if(is_readable($filename)) {
    echo "$filename is readable<br />";
} else {
    echo "$filename is not readable<br />";
}

echo "Real Path: ".realpath($filename)."<br />";

$filename = 'connection.php';

echo "Permissions: ".substr(sprintf("%o",fileperms($filename)),-4)."<br />";
echo "File Owner: ".fileowner($filename)."<br />";
echo "File Group: ".filegroup($filename)."<br />";

if(is_executable($filename)) {
    echo ("$filename is executable<br />");
} else {
    echo ("$filename is not executable<br />");
}

if(is_readable($filename)) {
    echo "$filename is readable";
} else {
    echo "$filename is not readable";
}

echo "Real Path: ".realpath($filename)."<br />";
```

Comment: can we see what's in connection.php? minus credentials

Comment: is this for the example or are the values enclosed in [] ? $connnection_server = "server";
$connection_database = "db";
$connection_user =  "username";
$connection_password = "password";

Comment: @Phil Pafford- I added the brackets for the example. The real values are in the live file.

Comment: @Phil - I don't understand that last bit. Where do I add the include?

Comment: The database is on another server.

Comment: try require("connection.php"); this should stop the script execution on error

Comment: @Phil - not working. It seems to be ignoring include statements.

Comment: @Moshe I saw you have admin.php in your edit code above, thought you might had put that by mistake but you had corrected the edit above to read connection.php. Just thought you might replace connection.php with admin.php, but try my suggestion above

Comment: Just for kicks can you hard code the path to the include script? include(/hard/code/path/to/connection.php');

Comment: Phil - Yep, just for kicks. No, it doesn't help.

Comment: interesting thread that might help: http://www.dmcinsights.com/phorum/read.php?9,28748

Comment: added a test to compare files and permission

Answer (score 1):

> After some frustration, I decided to check my include and it turns out that the following code is not including my connection variables file

To determine if this is really the case, try the following:

1. In connection.php add the line: `die('This is connection.php.');` 
    See if the script dies. If so, the file is being included.
2. Before 
   `$link = mysql_connect($connection_server, $connection_user, $connection_password)`
    add: 
   `var_dump($connection_server)`
    and see if the connection server is output when you run the script, or if something like "NULL" appears instead. If it's null, you know the variable isn't being set.

---

**EDIT 1**:

As per [your message in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/235622#235622):

You cannot include a remote file like using `http://your.domain/connection.php`. Well you can but as you saw, it won't work. include("http://your.domain/new/connection.php");  means "execute connection.php as a seperate request and include it's output".

You want:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/connection.php");
```

Comment: And you should be happy that it works in that way. If your script can get credentials in that way, everyone else can do that.

Comment: I am editing my post back and forth, because [what's happening here is unclear](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/235682#235682)...

Answer (score 1):

> Put error_reporting(E_ALL); before
>   mysql_connect(). Do you get notices
>   about undefined variables? –
>   Lekensteyn

---

> @Lekensteyn - Yes, I do. – Moshe

Put the following in `config.php`, before `$connections_included`.

```
global $connections_included, $connection_server, $connection_user, $connection_password;
```

It'll export those variables to the global scope.